# kubernetes Load Balancing with Parallels RAS or NGINX

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, parallels

Maybe I am way off in my pursuit to create as close to real a Kubernetes setup on a local network :-)

Is it possible to use Parallels(Desktop) RAS as a Loadbalancer for Kubernetes?

```
1. I am running a master node in Ubuntu on Parallels Desktop 
2. And some worker nodes also in Parallels Desktop
```

Both using a bridge network.

It would be cool if it is possible to have a setup including a LoadBalancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/), [KubeVIP](https://kube-vip.io/), or [Keepalived-operator](https://github.com/redhat-cop/keepalived-operator) (with HAProxy). I played around with KubeVIP but now use MetalLB L2 in my RasberryPi based Kubernetes cluster. MetalLB BGP would be even better if you have a router that supports the protocol (such as Unifi). The following references might help further:

1. https://www.openshift.com/blog/self-hosted-load-balancer-for-openshift-an-operator-based-approach
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PLw1xalcYA
3. http://blog.cowger.us/2019/02/10/using-metallb-with-the-unifi-usg-for-in-home-kubernetes-loadbalancer-services.html